# Replace a variable in a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file containing Dialogue for an RPG I'm making, and I'd like to be able to place the players chosen name in it as it comes up. For example if the player's name was a

```
public string playerName = "Leon";
```

and in my JSON I had

```
"NPCIDxxGreeting":{
    "text": "Yo, _____, what's up?"
}
```

I'd like to be able to insert "Leon" wherever that blank space showed up in the dialogue JSON. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use tokens and string.Replace. For example `var greeting = "hello $name"` and `greeting.Replace("$name", "Leon")`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is replace a token in your string with another string. If your JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "NPCIDxxGreeting":{
        "text": "Yo, $name, what's up?"
    }
}
```

You can load this string and then replace `$name` with the `playerName` variable.

If you're using JSON.NET, you can parse the JSON file like this:

```
dynamic dialogue = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Then, pull the string out and replace the `$name` token:

```
var greeting = dialogue["NPCIDxxGreeting"].text.ToString();
var playerGreeting = greeting.Replace("$name", playerName);
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates it: [Replace variable in JSON](https://dotnetfiddle.net/czt3Gr)

Answer (score 0):

.NET supports Json converting. So basically you read in the file contents and just parse the JSON information.

Example

```
public class Stats
{
    public int attack;
    public string playerName;
    public float speed;
    ......
}
public static List<string>GetJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.json"))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Stats> stats = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stats>>(json);
        return stats ; 
    }
}
```